# How do I remove an array from an array in numpy?

Tags: python, list, numpy

If I have

```
a = [[1, 1], [1, 2]]
b = [[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3]]
```

Where a and b are numpy arrays, how can I get this?

```
c = b - a = [[1, 3]]
```

Because np.delete does it by index not value. I have tried to create a new array like this

```
for arr in b:
    if arr not in a:
        new.append(arr)
```

But it doesn't work, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

A few observations you should know:

1. `numpy` has nothing to do with what you showed.
2. What you showed uses built-in Python lists
3. To remove an item from a Python list, use `remove`. This is a `o(n)` operation.
4. Working code:

```
a = [1, 1]
b = [[1, 1], [1, 2]]

print(b)
b.remove(a)
print(b)
```

out:

```
[[1, 1], [1, 2]]
[[1, 2]]
```

Comment: @PoChenLiu The code in the question does not have numpy arrays. Show code that creates numpy arrays, or edit code that actually produces an error or unexpected output.

Answer (score 1):

Python provides a very powerful list feature "List Comprenhensions" that produce an effective and versatile way to conduct list manipulations in a very adaptable manner.

Considering the input lists you have provided, the output can be dervied within an optimal complexity :

```
  a = [1, 1]
  b = [[1, 1], [1, 2]]
  c = [x for x in b if x != a]
  print(c)
```

Printing 'c' will provide you :

```
[[1, 2]]
```

Note: Using built - in list method of `remove()` also assists in the same, but I just wanted to emphasize on the value of List Comprehensions in a dynamic language like Python.

Comment: Ah cripes I should edit the question. A is an array of rows I would like to remove!